# MSMQ poison message time in subqueue

Tags: .net, wcf, msmq, poison-queue

I wanna know for how long do poison messages live in the poison subqueue. I have been reading documentation and it does not seem to be clear... Thanks in advance

Comment: assuming that you are using WCF, look at there TimeToLive attribute on the binding  - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/netmsmqbinding

Comment: @Dhawalk thanks, I thought this attribute was only when the messages where in the receving queue.